# How can I retrieve exact stock prices from the past using yfinance interval tool in Python?

Tags: python, stock, yfinance

I want to create a python program that can print out a list with 5 elements, the current price of a stock being 1, and the other 4 being the past price of that stock in intervals of 60 minutes.

For example:

```
Current Price: $100
Price 60m ago: $81
Price 120m ago: $89
Price 180m ago: $103
Price 240m ago: $78
```

I tried to use the yfinance interval tool to print the prices in the past 60m, however it gives me, high, and low prices, I would like to get the exact prices of 60 minutes ago not the high and lows.

Comment: That's not how it works.  There is no "exact price" at any given point in time, because offers and asks have different prices, and trades do not take place on even 60 minute intervals.  Use the average, if you want.